# "I refer to him by, what I assume, is his nickname" vs "I refer to him by, what I assume, his nickname is"

Tags: clauses

I'm confused with the following sentances:

1. I refer to him by, what I assume, is his nickname: xxxx.
2. I refer to him by, what I assume, his nickname is: xxxx.
3. I refer to him by, what is his nickname: xxxx.
4. I refer to him by, what his nickname is: xxxx.

Which one is correct?

The reason that I'm confused is that I think it is uncommon to use what/who as the subject of a noun clause. And I don't know if it will be affected by introducing "I assume".

Comment: The sentence needs no commas: "I refer to him by what I assume is his nickname" works fine and is actually clearer than any commas can make it.

Comment: It would make the question much more focused if you only included everything after the first *What is correct?* It's not clear form the first half with all the commas if the commas (with or without the *what I assume* part) are the focus of a second question or not. As it is, I can't tell what you are specifically asking—or if you're asking multiple things.

Comment: @Robusto I wonder if it is correct to use "what" as the subject? Is the word order in sentence 1 and 3 grammatically correct?

Comment: None of these is acceptable in normal writing. 1' "I refer to him by what, I assume, is his nickname: xxxx" works, as does the uncommaed version Robusto suggests.

Comment: Put the comma before "by". Say "I refer to him, by what I assume is his nickname; xxxx."

Comment: @Noah that comma is incorrect according the punctuation rules I learned.  The adverbial prepositional phrase "by what I assume is his nickname" is not incidental or parenthetical.

Answer (score 1):

When nonessential elements are added to a sentence, it should be possible to remove them completely and still have the sentence make good sense.

So the sentence without the nonessential elements would be:
*I refer to him by his nickname: xxxx.*

Then add the nonessential element: *I refer to him by, which I assume is, his nickname: xxxx.*

Here is more information, if you are interested:
[Purdue Online Writing Lab](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/commas_with_nonessential_elements.html) and
[Englishgrammar101](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-12/punctuation-end-marks-and-commas/lesson-9/commas-with-nonessential-elements)

If you don't want to end the nonessential element with "is", you can modify it to read: *I refer to him by, under my assumption, his nickname: xxxx.*

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your message about nonessential elements sounds fine, but you should check the sentence you proposed that includes the nonessential element. It doesn't read grammatically.